# Capybara test intermittently failing when using Selenium driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, testing, capybara

I've got an integration test here which is passing flawlessly using the poltergeist driver every time, but when I run this test using Selenium it passes on average 3 times and fails 1 time.

```
def fill_in_inclusion_criteria
  find("div.measure#age label[for='16']").click
  find("div.measure#substance_use_met label[for='1']").click
  find("div.measure#participant_consent label[for='1']").click
  click_link("Next")
end
```

When it fails, the error that I get back is this

```
expected to find css "div.measure#participant_consent" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

The participant consent button appears when `div.measure#age label[for='16']` is clicked, so it's dependent on Javascript. I see this happening in Firefox most of the time, but when it errors, the div isn't visible on the page.

It seems like it's not waiting for the element to display on the page before clicking it, but I thought that wrapping it in a "find" waits for the element to be visible on the page before trying to click it?

Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

The one confusing thing with your question is that the error message you posted isn't actually for the code you've shown, since if it was the error message would be `expected to find css "div.measure#participant_consent label[for='1']" ...` .  Assuming that's just a copy paste error/from a previous slightly different version of the code and the line you specified is where the error is actually coming from:

Since the previous find/click lines are working there are 2 potential reasons for the third one to not find the label element

1. The age label[for='16'] element click either isn't actually occurring, or is occurring before the JS that enables the showing behavior is attached.  You can check for this by adding a `sleep` for a few seconds before it and seeing whether the failures go away
2. The participant_consent find/click isn't waiting long enough for the element to appear.  `find` waits up to `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` seconds for elements to appear, so if that is long enough you could increase that setting, or pass a `:wait` option to find to override the setting for that call

   find("div.measure#participant_consent label[for='1']", wait: 10).click

Technically, there is a third potential cause but it's highly unlikely due to the sporadic nature of the failure, which would be a JS failure on the page.  You can check for this by rescuing the error and pausing your test so that you can look at the developer console in the browser for any errors.